# action.payload in creactAsyncThunk is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to get user data from api using axios with **createAsyncThunk**, and want the user data to be stored in state by the fulfilled action dispatched by the **createAsyncThunk**.

As mentioned in the [docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#return-value)

> if the promise resolved successfully, dispatch the fulfilled action with the promise value as action.payload.

But the action.payload in undefined in the **fulfilled action creator**.

Here is my code.

```
/// Create Async Thunk
export const fetchUserData = createAsyncThunk(
  'user/fetchUserData',
  (payload, { dispatch }) => {
    axios
      .get('/user')
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data);
        //Used this as a work around for storing data
        dispatch(setUser(res.data));

        return res.data;
       })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
        return err;
      });
  }
);

/// On Fulfilled
const userSlice = createSlice({
...
  extraReducers:{
  ...
  [fetchUserData.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
        // Payload is undefined
        state.data = action.payload
      },
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[createAsyncThunk](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#createasyncthunk) accepts two parameters:

1. `type`
2. `payloadCreator`

Where `payloadCreator` is a callback function that should return a **promise** (containing the result of some asynchronous logic) or a **value** (synchronously).

So, you can either write:

```
export const fetchUserData = createAsyncThunk(
  'user/fetchUserData',
  (payload, { dispatch }) => {
    return axios.get('/user'); // Return a promise
  }
);
```

or

```
export const fetchUserData = createAsyncThunk(
  'user/fetchUserData',
  async (payload, { dispatch, rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('/user')
      return response // Return a value synchronously using Async-await
    } catch (err) {
      if (!err.response) {
        throw err
      }
      return rejectWithValue(err.response)
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks I understand now what was my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

An addition to @Ajeet Shah's answer:

According [to the documentation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#payloadcreator) a rejected promise must return either

- an Error-instance, as in `new Error(<your message>)`,
- a plain value, such as a descriptive String,
- or a `RejectWithValue` return by `thunkAPI.rejectWithValue()`

With the first two options, and I haven't tested the last option, the payload will also by `undefined`, but an `error` parameter will be given containing your rejected message.

See this example:

```
const loginAction = createAsyncThunk(
  "user/login",
  (payload, { getState }) => {
    const { logged_in, currentRequestId, lastRequestId } = getState().login;

    // Do not login if user is already logged in
    if (logged_in) {
      return Promise.reject(new Error(Cause.LoggedIn));
    }

    // Do not login if there is a pending login request
    else if (lastRequestId != null && lastRequestId !== currentRequestId) {
      return Promise.reject(new Error(Cause.Concurrent));
    }

    // May as well try logging in now...
    return AccountManager.login(payload.email, payload.password);
  }
);
```